# Swiper V6.4.1 how to create multiple swipers on a single page using SWIPER V.6.4.1

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

So guys, i've been busy for this work we are developing an anime website , so theres a problem ,

i want my website composed atleast multiple Swipers , for the header and bottom. using SWIPER V.6.4.1

guys can you help me how to create multiple swipers on a single page?

Comment: I've try initiating the class names,css and even the javascript but it doesnt work..

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: There's no need to check codes because the swipers I used came from Swiper v.6.4.1

Comment: The only question is how can i create multiple swipers on a single page, you can also visit the site i've talking about.... "Swiper"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by giving each swiper slide a unique selector:
For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-container s1">
  ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-container s2">
  ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-container s3">
  ...
</div>
```

and in your script:

```
    var swiper1 = new Swiper('.s1', { /* Options for slide 1 here */ });

    var swiper2 = new Swiper('.s2', { /* Options for slide 2 here */ });

    var swiper3 = new Swiper('.s3', { /* Options for slide 3 here / });
```

**Note: s1,s2 and s3 are unique classes.**